# When I use fstab to automount a disk I can't see data on it

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab

I have a disk formated to ext4 with around 100GB movies folder and I want it to auto mount, so I added a line to `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=73258dba-f658-4f81-9b2a-8928da2eab75      /home/[user]/mount     ext4    rw,auto,user    0       2
```

and restarted

After restart the disk is mounted I can access and rw data in `/home/[user]/mount` but the movies folder is  not shown anymore. With  `ls -la` I see nothing. When I comment out this line in `fstab` and restart again mount is `/media/[user]/73258dba-f658-4f81-9b2a-8928da2eab75/` and the movies are back.

Owner for disk in media is `[user]:[user]` and `/home/[user]/mount` is the same with `drwxrwxr-x` permissions.

Can it be caused by hidden folder `lost+found` which is on the disk and belongs to `root:root`? Or is there something else I got wrong?

Comment: Seems odd, and doesn't seem like a permissions issue. I recommend mounting external drives in `/media/user/mydrive` (make a mountpoint first like `mkdir /media/user/mydrive` and then put that in the `fstab` line) rather than in your home directory. I don't know if that will make any difference to this problem though

Comment: Is that your real fstab-line or is `[user]` replaced with your real user-name?

Comment: it's not real fstab user is only substitute.

Comment: Thank you @Zanna, tried to mount it to `/media/user/mydrive` and it's working now. But still dunno why it can't be mounted to user local folder, maybe it's that user option in fstab.

Comment: I'm not sure either why it did not work! Please could you write an answer to your own question (in the answer space below) briefly saying that you made a new mountpoint at that location, and including your new `fstab` line? This could help someone else in future...

Comment: As you suggested i make new directory `mkdir -p /media/user/mydrive` then i edited `fstab` to : `UUID=73258dba-f658-4f81-9b2a-8928da2eab75       /media/user/mydrive  ext4    rw,auto,user    0       2`

Comment: "After restart the disk is mounted" - how did you test that (using `df` or `mount`)? If the `mount` does not succeed, `/home/user/mount`is just a simple directory, and of course you can write/read there. And maybe `/home` is on a different partition (not `/`) and not available at the moment of the execution of the `mount` command?

Comment: I have checked it through `mount` command and it pointed to `/home/user/mount` but directory was empty.

Comment: @ridgy I think if the partition fails to mount during boot you couldn't boot successful unless you have the `nofail`-option in the fstab-line. I have a partition mounted on a folder in my home-directory and it works flawless, but in my case it is a NTFS-partition and I am on UbuntuStudio, but why it shouldn't work with an EXT4-partition on Ubuntu? Quite mystic...